# Calculate Rate of Return for a table shown below using excel

Tags: excel, math, xlsx

This is a simple math question that i will be using excel formula for. I have 5 columns. broken up like this

```
 Total Rentals| Out | New rented|Returned|Available|rate of retun
           200     40          40        0      160 
           200     60          20        0      140            x
           200     90          30        4      114            x
           200    150          60       20       70            x
```

How do i find the rate of return?

Comment: What is the expected output (values)?

Comment: What do you mean by "rate of return," since you are not using it in its [traditional sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_return)?